# How to fix the location of a comment with pane freeze?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I'm having issues again with an old Excel bug (currently version 'Home and Business 2016'):

I use "Freeze panes" for keeping several headings in my worksheet.
I add a comment to one of the headings, that comment spans over different lines.

As the comment spans over different lines, it goes over the "pane freezer", that "pane freezer" cuts my comment into two parts.
If I start scrolling, the bottom part of my comment also scrolls, making the comment unreadable, as you can see in following screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

In order to workaround this bug, I have edited my comment, and I have placed it above of the "pane freezer", but after having finished that, next time that I show the comment, it goes back to its original position, which causes the bug to appear again.

Is there a way to save the location of a comment, in order for the comment not to be split during scrolling?

Comment: I don't think there would be a way to fix it, unless you use a macro to keep it in place.

Comment: What if you pulled the comment completely above the bottom of row 4? What if you resize it to fit in rows 1:4?

Comment: @Batman: this is exactly what I did, but afterwards Excel puts the comment back to its original position.

Comment: Do you need the comment to be there at all times or would it be OK if it just showed up if `B4` is selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a kludge, but it might be good enough for what you need.

Select the file and go to `Data -> Data Tools -> Data Validation` and select the second tab in the dialog box.

[image]

Type in your note

You will notice that the message does not appear when the cell is not selected.

[image]

It does appear when the slide is selected and will not move as you scroll down (provided it's with a cell that is frozen)

[image]

[image]